# Colours changed in cmyk

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs5, cmyk, color-reproduction

I have designed a book wrapper in CMYK mode in Photoshop cs5. I am using laptop for designing. When I send the design through mail the colours are getting changed. What should be done to get the same output

Comment: how are the colors changing? what is the other person using to open the file? What is the file format?

Comment: Has your monitor has been calibrated? Did you get the profile of your printer? Did you enable soft proofing? Did you ask for a hard proof? Basically if you did not calibrate your monitor or work your colors from a color book, and ignore monitor, with correct calibration info then all bets are off. Even when you do this some colors change due to medium change.

Comment: When you say "mail" I assume you mean email? (I still think of "mail" as putting something in a physical mailbox with a stamp on it).. also what are you mailing? An image? A Photoshop document? How are they changed? When viewed in the email? When opened in Photoshop at the other end? When printed?

Answer (score 1):

Since others have commented about monitor calibration, I'll talk about another issue it might be.

The issue is likely to do with how browsers interpret the CMYK values, since computers display in RGB.

To quickly answer your question, **there is nothing you can do to change how a CMYK image will be displayed inside an RGB color space**, that I'm aware of anyway.

That being said, if this is for print, stop previewing it inside your browser and open it inside the appropriate application for whichever file format you're using. For example, if I were to send someone a CMYK PDF, it will look as if the colors are inverted inside my email client, but when it's opened outside of a browser (inside Acrobat for example) the colors will be displayed pretty much how they should be.

If this design is not intended for print, then you need to switch the colorspace from CMYK to RGB.

Comment: thanks for the info..yes this book wrapper is intended for print.